# Razor: Navigate to new webpage

Tags: c#, razor, webbrowser-control, razor-pages

I am trying to navigate to another page in C# razor. Here is my code. But simply nothing happens. It seems that the thread is not starting at all:

```
@using System.Windows.Forms;
@using System;
@using System.Threading;

@{
    var message = "";

    void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
    {
        var th = new Thread(()=>
        {
            var br = new WebBrowser();
            br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
            Application.Run();
            br.Navigate(url);
        });
        th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        th.Start();
    }

    void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var br = sender as WebBrowser;
    }

    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
    runBrowserThread(uri);
}



<body>
    <span id="myspan">@message</span>

</body>
```

Comment: i just put the google.com as an example. I want actually to access to DOM of the page. But I am not even able to navigate to it.

Comment: This is a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why, on the server-side, do you want to load google.com (or some other website) and its contents?

Comment: I am not following. I want to access to an element on a HTML page to read its value. I assume it is a common issue or practice for many. I cannot do it using javascript as the domain is not same as the main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you start typing `using System.Windows.Forms` in a web application, you should know that you are doing something wrong.

The WebBrowser control has no place in ASP.NET. Instead, you should use the [HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) to make an HTTP request to the page that you want to fetch (or "scrape"). It has a [GetStringAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetStringAsync_System_String_) that returns the response (usually HTML if the resource you are requesting is a web page).

Once you have the HTML, there are a few ways to parse it. Avoid using Regex or string methods. Use a package like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack) or [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) for this instead. They are optimised for parsing the DOM.